# Verilog Finite State Machine not updating state

Tags: verilog, fpga

Edit - since question was closed as not specific enough

The block:

```
if( (FT6_RXF_N == 1) || (DataAvailable == 0) ) begin
   NextState <= STATE_BUS_TURN_AROUND_TWO;        // Doesn't seem to happen when DataAvailable == 0
   RequestData <= 0;                                  // Is happening when DataAvailable == 0
end
```

is only being partially executed.

original post below

I am trying to interface a Spartan 6 xc6slx FPGA to a FTDI FT601 USB3.0 FIFO.

I am having moderate success but have a bug I cannot fathom having looked at it for a couple of days now.

The FT601 Multi Channel protocol goes through 5 states IDLE - COMMAND - BUS TURN (type1) - DATA TRANSFER - BUS TURN (type2) - IDLE

I am having trouble in moving from the DATA TRANSFER phase at the end of the transaction, so want to close and return to IDLE.

There ate two ways this can happen. The FT601 reports its buffer is full, or on my side I have no more data.

On the positive edge of the FT601's clock, I check what the next state should be. On the negative edge I set this 'NextState' to the FSM 'CurrentState'

When determining the 'NextState', If I am in the DATA state, have no data I set a 'RequestData' buffer to low. Right now this just enables a counter to generate test data. Screenshot one shows that this condition is being detected as the blue trace 'DataAvailable' causes the green trace 'RequestData' to go low. But the Next State must not be being set to BusTurnTwo as the yellow trace 'FT6_WR_N' is not going high.

Eventually we do go to state BusTurnTwo as shown in screen shot two, but this seems to be caused by the other condition FT6_RXF_N (purple trace) going high, some 20 microseconds later.

[Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K6fFc.jpg)

[Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cDSxL.jpg)

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps
module FT601Controller(input FT6_Clk,
                       input FT6_RXF_N,
                              input FT6_TXE_N,
                              
                              output reg FT6_WR_N,
                              output reg [3:0] FT6_BE,
                              
                              inout [31:0] FT6_DATA,
                              
                              input [31:0] DataIn,
                              
                              input DataAvailable,
                              output reg RequestData
                      );
                            
   localparam STATE_IDLE = 0;
   localparam STATE_COMMAND_PHASE = 1;
   localparam STATE_BUS_TURN_AROUND_ONE = 2;
   localparam STATE_DATA_OUTPUT = 3;
   localparam STATE_BUS_TURN_AROUND_TWO = 4;
    
    
   reg [2:0] CurrentState;
   reg [2:0] NextState;
    reg [31:0] DataOut;
    
    wire FT601ChannelOneInReady;
    assign FT601ChannelOneInReady = ~(FT6_DATA[8]);
    
    assign FT6_DATA = DataOut;
    
   always @ (posedge FT6_Clk) begin
    
       case(CurrentState)
      
         STATE_IDLE: begin
            if( (FT601ChannelOneInReady == 1) && (DataAvailable == 1) ) begin
               NextState <= STATE_COMMAND_PHASE;
            end
            else begin
               NextState <= STATE_IDLE;
            end
         end
            
         STATE_COMMAND_PHASE: begin
            NextState <= STATE_BUS_TURN_AROUND_ONE;
         end
            
         STATE_BUS_TURN_AROUND_ONE: begin
            NextState <= STATE_DATA_OUTPUT;
        RequestData <= 1;
         end

         STATE_DATA_OUTPUT: begin
            if( (FT6_RXF_N == 1) || (DataAvailable == 0) ) begin
               NextState <= STATE_BUS_TURN_AROUND_TWO;        // Doesn't seem to happen when DataAvailable == 0
           RequestData <= 0;                                  // Is happening when DataAvailable == 0
            end
            else begin
               NextState <= STATE_DATA_OUTPUT;
            end;
         end

         STATE_BUS_TURN_AROUND_TWO: begin
            NextState <= STATE_IDLE;
         end        

         default: begin
            NextState <= STATE_IDLE;
                RequestData <= 0;
         end                
      
        endcase
        
   end
            

   always @ (negedge FT6_Clk) begin

      CurrentState <= NextState;
    
      case (NextState)
    
         STATE_COMMAND_PHASE: begin
            FT6_WR_N <= 0;
                FT6_BE <= 4'h1;
            DataOut[7:0] <= 8'h01;
         end

         STATE_BUS_TURN_AROUND_ONE: begin
            FT6_BE <= 4'hF;
         end

         STATE_DATA_OUTPUT: begin
                FT6_BE <= 4'hF;
                DataOut <= DataIn;
         end

         STATE_BUS_TURN_AROUND_TWO: begin
            FT6_WR_N <= 1;
                DataOut[31:16] <= 16'hFFFF;
            DataOut[15:8] <= 8'bZZZZZZZZ;
            DataOut[7:0] <= 8'hFF;
         end            
        
         STATE_IDLE : begin
                FT6_WR_N <= 1;
            FT6_BE <= 4'hF;
            DataOut[15:8] <= 8'bZZZZZZZZ;
            DataOut[7:0] <= 8'hFF;
            DataOut[31:16] <= 16'hFFFF;
            end
            
           default: begin   // also STATE_IDLE
            FT6_WR_N <= 1;
            FT6_BE <= 4'hF;
            DataOut[15:8] <= 8'bZZZZZZZZ;
            DataOut[7:0] <= 8'hFF;
            DataOut[31:16] <= 16'hFFFF;
         end
        
      endcase
    
   end  
                             
                             
   initial begin
      CurrentState = STATE_IDLE;
        NextState = STATE_IDLE;
        RequestData <= 0;
   end


endmodule*
```

Double checked documentation and Verilog code. Used Oscilloscope to probe with cheap probes and crocodile ground leads, so not good SI but good enough to see what's happening

Comment: try to simulate it first and debug in simulation.

Comment: Everything I have tried works fine when simulated using isim

Answer (score 0):

I cannot tell exactly what is causing the behavior you are observing, but best guess would be bounce on the input pad or logic timing.

Your screen shots show a lot of bounce (oscillation after transitioning low-to-high or high-to-low). So it is possible `DataAvailable` was above the voltage threshold when evaluating. Some FPGA boards have de-bounce built it; so check your manual. If it doesn't, consider flopping your input for one or two cycles before using with your logic. This will add cycle delay.

You are using `@ (posedge FT6_Clk)` and `@ (negedge FT6_Clk)`. This creates two different types of flops which may result additional routing that can impact your timing. You logic is simple enough that can be but in one always block. If you use one always block you will not need the `NextState`. Or you could use the two always block approach where one is synchronous and the other is pure combination logic. I'm not going to rewrite your code, but I highly recommend you do. By making this change it should allow better LUT optimization and simpler routing.

One always block:

```
always @(posedge FT6_Clk) begin
  if (!rst_n) begin
    CurrentState <= STATE_IDLE;
    // ... other reset ...
  end
  else begin
    case(CurrentState)
      // ... case conditions to assign flip-flops ...
    endcase
  end
end
```

Two always blocks:

```
always @(posedge FT6_Clk) begin
  if (!rst_n) begin
    CurrentState <= STATE_IDLE;
    // ... other reset (non-blocking; <=) ...
  end
  else begin
    CurrentState <= NextState;
    // ... simple assignments to assign flip-flops (non-blocking; <=) ...
    endcase
  end
end
always @* begin
  NextState = CurrentState; // default assignment
  // ... other default assignments (blocking; =) ...
  case(CurrentState)
    // ... case conditions to assign combination logic (blocking; =) ...
  endcase
end
```

---

Other issue:
`DataOut` is a register and should not be assigned to Z. In synthesize, assigning a register to X or Z usually tells the synthesizer to treat the assignment as don't care. Some synthesizer are picky and may have specific requirements for don't care assignments. I have not works with a synthesizer that treats assigning Z to a register as a tri-state high-impedance.

If you want `FT6_DATA` to be bidirectional per byte, the it should be assigned something line this :

```
assign FT6_DATA[31:24] = OutputByteEnable[3] ? DataOut[31:24] : 8'hzz;
assign FT6_DATA[23:16] = OutputByteEnable[2] ? DataOut[23:16] : 8'hzz;
assign FT6_DATA[15: 8] = OutputByteEnable[1] ? DataOut[15: 8] : 8'hzz;
assign FT6_DATA[ 7: 0] = OutputByteEnable[0] ? DataOut[ 7: 0] : 8'hzz;
```

Some FPGA boards that support bidirectional ports should use specific modules from their standard cell library. Check your manual.